# Disable net command

Tags: windows-server-2003, command-line-interface, security

How can I disable the command line net command in windows server 2003? It would probably be good to do so for security purposes.

Comment: Can you describe the security purpose as an example? (Concern: is there actually a security issue with NET, or is the security issue something that preventing the use of NET masks, but does not address?)

Comment: Just as a added layer of protection in case a hacker gets shell access, so that they can't make a account for themselves.

Comment: Only Administrators (and Power Users, which are generally recommended against due to privilege escalation possibilities) could do that legitimately - if a hacker has admin access to a box, it's already game over.

Comment: @TristanK: +10 on your immediately prior comment if I could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to disable a command is with [Software Restriction Policies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457006.aspx) which will allow you to use group policy to disable the ability of a command to run for users you choose the policy to apply to.

Comment: Disallowing software with Software Restriction Policy isn't very effective. All an attacker needs to do is make a copy of the disallowed program, append a single byte to the end of the program, and the program will execute w/o issue. Software Restriction Policy is really only effective when it's run in the "Deny All, Allow Exceptions" mode.

Comment: Correct, applocker (the newest version) is more effective